# Unable to connect Studio3T with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have installed Studio3T for mongodb then I create a new connection and put below mentioned detail:

On Server tab, connection Type: Direct Connection
Server: localhost, port: 27017
On Authentication tab, Authentication Mode: Basic (MONGODB-CR or SCRAM-SHA-1)
User Name: superadmin
Password: 123456

after I click on Connect it is waiting for almost 45 seconds and then failed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joKse.png)

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting from mongo console? mongo --username alice --password --authenticationDatabase admin --host mongodb0.examples.com --port 28015

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you try to connect with Authentication Mode set to None? If that doesn't work, then we recommend double-checking the user credentials because there might be a discrepancy (e.g. text states `superadmin`, screenshot shows `superuser`).

Comment: It connects when  I set Authentication  mode to None.